# SCORM Adobe Presenter 7 Content did not call doInitialize in LMS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, adobe, scorm

I am developing an ASP.NET based LMS that uses Adobe Presenter 7 SCORM content.
According to SCORM 2004 RTE documentation, the SCO will automatically search for the SCORM API and initialize communication.
I've included the SCORM content and the API Wrapper in one page.
When I tried to run the code, the SCO really did find the API, but it did not call for doInitialize() function in the API.
What did I do wrong? I really appreciate your responses.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <iframe src="JS/SCORM_2004_APIWrapper.js" name="API_1484_11" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
        <iframe src="SCORM2004Sample/SCORM.htm" width="800" height="600"></iframe>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SCORM 2004 API must have an Initialize() method (not doInitialize) to initiate the communication.

FX

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. I downloaded the SCORM_2004_APIWrapper.js from ADL's site, so I think it is standard for all SCORM content. I just put the entire .zip output file from the Adobe Presenter's file and extracted it. I didn't change any part of the file. Should the SCORM API for Adobe Presenter scorm file be different? Anyway I tried changing the function in the API into Initialize() and it's still didn't get called. fyi, i got a javascript error "TypeError: g_objAPI.Initialize is not a function".